# I cannot separate scraped data into different category

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I need help from python expert. This is a site where I have to scrape table data and separate into four different category then convert it into excel file but problem is all table category's classes are same.

There should be different four classes but same four classes

Thanks
Mariful

[Website for scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbeLk.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.kpaa.or.kr/kpaa/eng/list.do?"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find_all(class_='title')
for item in items:
    n = item.text
    print(n)
df = pd.Dataframe({'name':n, 'office':n, 'phone':n, 'email':n})
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is i try to convert single data to 2D list to use in data pandas data frame.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.kpaa.or.kr/kpaa/eng/list.do?"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

data_list = [td.getText(strip=True, separator=',').split(',') for td in  soup.find('div', {'class':'cont_box2'}).find_all('tr')[:-1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)

df.to_excel('x.xlsx')
```

Comment: please mark answer as accepted if it correctly solved your issue :)